# Is possible with Qt to have pen behind brush?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

Is it possible and how ? Even SVG has that ability. Is the rendering order in that matter fixed in Qt?

Comment: Are you using raw QPainter, QGraphicsView or QtQuick? And what's pen behind fill supposed to be? semi-transparent fill on top of outline?

Comment: Didn't mention....I use QBrush with QGraphicsItems. Somewhere it's called "stroke behind fill" and that means pen wouldn't overlap brush area - or rendering first pen / second brush. I should edit title to make it more clear.